# What do file descriptor 3 and 4 stand for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-descriptor

Execute below code in `irb` (no preceding commands) will get `5`.

```
f = File.open("./test.txt")
puts f.fileno
```

File descriptor number `0`, `1`, `2` stand for `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, `STDERR`. What do 3 and 4 stand for in ruby?

Enviroment: *Lubuntu 14.04 64bit, Ruby 1.9.3 under rvm*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File descriptors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082001/file-descriptors)

Comment: @sethvargo It id not a *dup* question.

Comment: "possible" duplicate of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Standard Input, Output, & Error](http://readruby.io/io#standard-streams) :

> When it is started by the shell, a program inherits three open files, with file descriptors 0, 1, and 2, called the standard input, the standard output, and the standard error. All of these are by default connected to the terminal, so if a program only reads file descriptor 0 and writes file descriptors 1 and 2, it can do I/O without having to open files. If the program opens any other files, they will have file descriptors 3, 4, etc.

**Update**

```
$stdin.fileno    # => 0
$stdout.fileno   # => 1
$stderr.fileno # => 2
File.open('test1').fileno # => 7
File.open('test2').fileno # => 8
File.open('test.txt').fileno # => 9
```

Now lets try to read the *filename* from the *file descriptors* using [`for_fd`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-for_fd) method.

```
File.for_fd(7) # => #<File:fd 7> # refers file test1
File.for_fd(8) # => #<File:fd 8> # refers file test2
File.for_fd(9) # => #<File:fd 9> # refers file test.txt
```

Opps!, these are not possible, as file descriptors 3,4,5,6 are used by **RubyVM**.

```
File.for_fd(3) # => 
# The given fd is not accessible because RubyVM reserves it (ArgumentError)
File.for_fd(4) # => 
# The given fd is not accessible because RubyVM reserves it (ArgumentError)
File.for_fd(5) # => 
# The given fd is not accessible because RubyVM reserves it (ArgumentError)
File.for_fd(6) # => 
# The given fd is not accessible because RubyVM reserves it (ArgumentError)
```

Note : My Ruby version is - *2.0.0-p451* in *openSUSE13.1*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a ruby specific thing.  Each file-ish thing you have has a descriptor assigned to it.  0 1 2 are assigned by default to what you've mentioned.  As you open more files, they get assigned the next available descriptor.  If you try opening 6 files, they'll all get different numbers, and if you change the order you open them in, they'll get another set of numbers.

If you skip one, it probably means your program opened up another file that you didn't realize.  My money would be on one or more ruby libraries, but I wouldn't swear to that.