# Don't need to open file descriptors when redirecting them?

Tags: bash, stream, file-descriptor

I've read (e.g. here: [How do file descriptors work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082001/how-do-file-descriptors-work)) that to use file descriptors 3 - 9 I need to open them first. Trying to use them without it produces an error:

```
function f()
{
    echo hi 1>&3
}
f
```

Output:

```
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

However, if I redirect it when calling the function everything seems to work fine:

```
f 3>&1
```

Output:

```
hi
```

So do I need to open file descriptors or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need to open a new file descriptor and as a good practice you should close it in the end like this:

```
f() {
    # open fd=3 redirecting to 1 (stdout)
    exec 3>&1

    # redirect stdout to fd=3
    echo hi >&3

    # close fd=3
    exec 3>&-
}
```

Note that when you run `f 3>&1` while invoking function you are actually opening file descriptor `3` by redirecting it to `&1` (stdout).

Comment: If I do `f 3>&1 ; f` then the 2nd call to `f` still returns error - file descriptor 3 isn't open at that point. So I still don't understand how this works.

Comment: Also shouldn't you open and close `3` outside of `f`? I know it's just an example but as it is your definition of `f` doesn't seem to make much sense (it effectively prints to stdout anyway).

Comment: Well we require an extra fd when we want to treat it differently. e.g. some folks want to redirect all stdout/stderr to a log file while still want to keep freedom of writing some progress etc to terminal. Since we didn't redirect stdout/stderr  to any log file so here `$3` is just a copy of `&1`.