# What does `exec {logOutFd}>&1 {logErrFd}>&2` do?

Tags: bash

I don't understand [this line](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/8a7d5c039cacc83bd1926aaabc04d541e04a1460/nixos/modules/system/boot/stage-2-init.sh#L92):

```
exec {logOutFd}>&1 {logErrFd}>&2
```

There are no variable dereferences, and it seems to be just a no-op, like running `exec` with no parameters. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` with no parameters is used to start redirections that last for the rest of the script.

From the Bash manual section on [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form *{varname}*. In this case, for each redirection operator except `>&-` and `<&-`, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to *{varname}*.

So this is duplicating stdout and stderr to new file descriptors, and setting the variables `$logOutFd` and `$logErrFd` to these descriptors, respectively.

This allows later code that executes while stdout or stderr are redirected to write to the original stdout or stderr, with

```
echo stdout message >&$logOutFd
```

Answer (score -1):

Reviewing other preceding script: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ANixOS%2Fnixpkgs%20%20logOutFd&type=code

[image]

And reading:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082184/3957754
- https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0009.html

They are using complex i/o redirections to return the stream pointer from some files previously open (8 and 9 position) to the classic stdout and stderr

```
exec 8>&1 9>&2
```

Comment: Neither https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082184/3957754 nor https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0009.html explain the syntax in the question though. At least, I could find no mention of the same syntax or the word "curly".