# Alternative for openSSL

Tags: cryptography, openssl, pki

I have academical project to build communicator with Public Key Infrastructure. For communication between server and clients I'll use SSL/TLS and I need for them certificates. I have to build Certificate Authority with CRL and I can do this with openSSL but this tool is only good for manual administrative not for making certificates automatically in remote CA.

To be clear: Clients must register and login to communicator using certificates but it should be made invisible for them. I've tried running openSSL as process in Java but it's not working properly - [my previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033683/java-process-streams).

Have you any good advice for making simple PKI?

Comment: they said "simple pki".  heh.  heh.

Answer (score 1):

You can use and extend [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/). It takes some getting used to but it has support for some HSM's, and it should not be hard to create a small PKI with it. Open source.

Comment: Would this solve your problem, mydew, please accept or indicate what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A replacement for simple operations of OpenSSL, would be Bouncy castle. To have better CA support you should also use the EJBCA.
To create certificates automatically in the client (I assume you use a client web browser) is a bit trickier. Some browser can generate private client keys and then get them signed by the CA server.
[Generating client side certificates in browser and signing on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197484/generating-client-side-certificates-in-browser-and-signing-on-server)
In that case, I would also use the EJBCA to make it manageable.